# Random crashes with Hitman 3 on Linux via Steam Play/Proton

Tags: technical-issues, linux, steam-play, hitman-3

This is a question mainly for people playing Hitman 3 on Linux.

I am trying to play Hitman 3 via Steam Play (Proton) on pc running Ubuntu 20.04 but I have random crashes in the level Chongqing. After a random time in game the game simply closes and brings me back to the desktop. No error messages are shown. This happens after a random time in game. Sometimes after 5 minutes, after 10 minutes, after 20 minutes and the like. Didn’t had this problem in the previous levels.

What I’ve tried so far: lowering all graphics settings, trying different versions of proton, reinstalling the whole game. Nothing worked.

Here are my specs:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 
Platform: Steam (using Steam Play/Proton) 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 (six-core processor x 12) 
GPU: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB 
Memory: 16GB

I also run a benchmark and the game is between 30 and 60 FPS. Average was something about 45.

In case there are any Linux gamers out there and have an idea of what might cause the problem, I am thankful for any help! Ideas and opinions from non-Linux users are welcome too, of course.

Many thanks!

PS: I also asked this question on the Hitman forums. Hope that's ok.

Comment: There's a log somewhere that would include information. Without that any attempts are a shot in the dark.

Comment: If your installation is default, please add `PROTON_LOG=1 %command%` to your launch options. That will create a log file on your user home. Sharing with us will make it easier to help.

You can also try some other proton versions, here are some suggestions https://www.protondb.com/app/1659040

Answer (score -1):

AMD is notorious for its problematic Linux drivers. It really supports Linux poorly. If you want to play on Linux you really need a Intel system.

At the very least you are stuck on your current version of Ubuntu. If you upgrade you have the very real possibility that the new update will have no drivers for the chipset.

Comment: How does this help answering the question at all ? There are several people running this game using [AMD](https://www.protondb.com/app/1659040) using similar setup as @op.