# Hitman 3 on Steam/Proton via Linux Fedora 38

Tags: steam, technical-issues, linux, steam-play, hitman-3

When trying to play Hitman 3 (2021) on Linux Fedora 38 via Steam Proton, the following problems sometimes occur for me:

1. Game does not start properly. After starting, there is a short black screen but then, the game just closes and throws me back to my desktop.
2. The game starts and can be played but sometimes freezes so that I have to quit using appropriate keyboard shortcuts.

Both problems do not always occur meaning that I still can play the game. However, both problems are not ultra rare so that they cause quite some annoyance.

Maybe someone has an idea what is going on for me and how the situation could be enhanced?

My specs:

OS: Fedora Linux 38 Workstation Edition 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor × 6 
Memory: 16 GB 
GPU: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] 
Nvidia Driver Version: 535.86.05

I tried various Proton versions but the only one which worked for me is Proton 6.3-8. With other versions, the game is not playable at all for me.

Here is a log file created via the steam launch option PROTON_LOG=1 %command%:

Part 1: https://pastebin.com/SctqZEjc#vkNXWLMm 
Part 2: https://pastebin.com/SW1FnLL3 
Part 3: https://pastebin.com/SGBnz0Ny

Many thanks for any suggestions!

PS: I asked a similar question several months ago (see here: [Random crashes with Hitman 3 on Linux via Steam Play/Proton](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/396618/random-crashes-with-hitman-3-on-linux-via-steam-play-proton)) but since my system has changed quite a bit since then, I decided to ask a new question providing more up-to-date background information.